# configure timestamp for mysql at the time of creating connection pool

Tags: java, mysql

Jersey restful web service. I want the default time that is inserted in createTime column in the data base table should be configured to IST instead of the default time which is in UTC(not sure). I don't want to change the timezone of mysql server. I want the timezone to be configured at the time of creating pooled connection and it should be reverted back to default when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default time zone in a MySql server is the system/OS time zone if not configured otherwise. You can set the time zone on per connection which will not affect the global setting of the server.

Example:

`> SET time_zone='+02:00'`

To read global and session time zone, use

`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: how to configure that in context.xml file.